# How to add more than 2 additional timezone clocks in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, clock, time-zone

Currently I have an ability to add only 2 additional time zones

[image]

How to add more?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 is it a dupe? This question is Windows 10, the "dupe" is Windows 7. Since the answer is the same, *should* we update the question (the "dupe") from Windows 7 to Windows (which also makes it a dupe)?

Comment: @Dave It's the same quesiton and still applies, but yeah it could use an edit... OK, I edited it to be less "7"-specific. :)